# Gridview column freeze not working in Mozilla

Tags: asp.net, css

I am trying to freeze the first column of a gridview in asp.net. My css code is

```
.CellLocked {
background-color:Gray;
position:relative;
left:expression(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.scrollLeft-1);
}
```

It is fine in IE but not working in mozilla. Plz help. Thanks...

Comment: please give a http://jsfiddle.net example

Answer (score 0):

Set this in your css:

```
position:absolute;
```